# SpingMVC + Angularjs+ POST with jsp

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, spring-mvc

new to angularjs. I am sure i am missing something.
I am unable to render the response send by server on jsp page if i hit server with angularjs's `$http` directive.

angularcode

```
// Read button Handler
$scope.readAll=function(){
    readTable($scope.clnfamilyArray);
    //send data to server
    testAddItem=function(){
        $http({
            'url' : 'http://localhost:9090/QuantumM/orbital/sendstatement/',
            'method' : 'POST',
            'headers': {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
            'data' : $scope.clnfamilyArray
        }).success(function(data){
            console.log(data);
        })
    }//end of function
    testAddItem();
}////end of readAll
```

spring code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sendstatement/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView welcome(@RequestBody String map) {      
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();        
    // BL   
    model.addObject("name",hTable.toHtml());
    model.setViewName("test");
    return model;
}
```

test.jsp

```
 <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>

<h1>Gradle - Spring MVC Hello World</h1>
<h2>Hello ${name}</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

Instead of rendering test.jsp. I am landing on the same page. But on console I can see the expected output..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>

<h1>Gradle - Spring MVC Hello World</h1>
<h2>Hello <table  border=1><tr><td  colspan=2>s</td></tr><tr><td  colspan=1>f</td><td  colspan=1>d</td></tr></table></h2>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there anything which I am missing ???
I wanted to landed on `test.jsp` not on my current calling page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing something, as you guessed.  The purpose of the $http call is to fetch the results of an HTTP call and provide it to your AngularJS application's model.  It is not meant to redirect you to a new page on another server.

The reason you see the page output in the console is due to the .success() portion of the http call:

```
$http({
 'url' : 'http://localhost:9090/QuantumM/orbital/sendstatement/',
    'method' : 'POST',
    'headers': {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
    'data' : $scope.clnfamilyArray
}).success(function(data){ // The data is passed here when received
    console.log(data);
})
```

It's an async call [handled by a promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).  So your app makes the http call, and then goes on its merry way.  When the data from that http call is available, it is passed to your .success() call and then you log it to the console.  [Here's a Plunk demo I did](http://plnkr.co/edit/lv8Kyu?p=info) showing how promises work in serial and parallel so you can see some of their benefit.

This is not the Angular way.  What you should be doing for a single-page-app in AngularJS is fetch the DATA from the server, not a rendered page, and then display it to the user with AngularJS views.

Instead of having your SpringMVC app render the view, have it pass the model back as JSON data.  That way, you will be able to easily show it to the user in your AngularJS view.

My guess is that if you took your example and had it return JSON, it would return something like:

```
{
  "name": "Bob"
}
```

Then you would change the .success() call to do something like this:

```
.success(function(data) {
  $scope.name = data.name;
})
```

And in your view, you would show it with:

```
<p>Hi {{name}}</p>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ohhh. 
But in that case, Is View in ModelAndView will be useless while working with angularjs ?
If no option then I have to switch on single page....

Comment: That's the case.  You could certainly try to make a bunch of separate single page apps, but that's not really what AngularJS was meant for.  That would be a lot of extra work and resources for no benefit.  Coming from Java myself, I understand how different the async Javascript/Angular way of thinking is. Here's a Plunk demoing promises a bit more that might help you: http://plnkr.co/edit/lv8Kyu?p=info

Comment: @sailor We use SpringMVC all the time to add AngularJS to existing Java/JSP based web apps.  We add Spring MVC controllers into the web app that supply the JSON data we then use to add interactive aspects to the app.  The formula works pretty well.